# Why analytical `dsolve` result so much different from `dsolve` numeric result?

Tags: maple

This is Maple 2016.2 on windows.

same ODE. Solution plotted from analytical `dsolve` looks so much different from the numerical solution by Maple. The difference shows on right side of the domain.  I suspect the numerical solution is correct and there is issue with either plotting the analytical solution, or the analytical solution given is not exactly correct?  How else could this be explained?

```
restart;
eps:=1/100:
ode:=eps*diff(y(x),x$2)+(x^2+1)*diff(y(x),x)-x^3*y(x)=0;
sol:=dsolve({ode,y(0)=1,y(1)=1},y(x)):
plot(rhs(sol),x=0..1,y=0..1);
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Here is the numerical solution plot

```
sol:=dsolve({ode,y(0)=1,y(1)=1},y(x),range=0..1,'numeric',maxmesh=500);
plots:-odeplot(sol, x=0..1,view=[0..1,0..1]);
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

btw, the numerical solution by Maple also agrees with the numerical solution by Mathematica.

**question is**: Which is the correct plot? From analytical or numerical solution? Is Maple analytical solution not correct? Or Am I making some error somewhere?

Comment: Perhaps it is a stiff ODE (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stiff_equation ) with the numerical solver unable to follow the almost vertical solution near the initial point. It drifts to nearby solutions which veer to be almost horizontal?

Comment: @JohnColeman it could also be the plotting routine for the analytical solution. The analytical solution is in terms of special function HeunT. These special functions has to be evaluated numerically to make the plot also. I do not know. In this problem, I expect actually to see a boundary layer on the left end only, and not at both ends when epsilon is very small. This is why I think the numerical solution is the correct one. But I am not 100% sure.

Comment: Maybe you should migrate the question to the Mathematics stack exchange (http://math.stackexchange.com/ ). It really isn't a programming question and you would be more likely to get useful feedback there from an expert in ODEs.